# Flutter overlay_support widget Not Initialized

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to create a notification on top using the overlay_support 1.2.1 widget. I did everything based on the example, but I always get a boot error as shown in the image below.

[image: Image error]

Answer (score 3):

wrap your material app with OverlaySupport.global()[picture showing what i mentioned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuU62.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I encounter error too but you can wrap your material app with OverlaySupport.global().
Note if you're dealing with multiple screen, you will wrap the main screen i.e. the first screen.

Answer (score 0):

**From**

```
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: MyApp()),
   );
}
```

**To**

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    OverlaySupport.global((
      child: MaterialApp(
      home: MyApp()),
    ),
   );
}
```